# Use of doParallel / doMC not only with foreach package

Tags: r, parallel-processing, doparallel, domc

all official tutorials [doParallel](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/doParallel.pdf), [doParallel-Vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/vignettes/gettingstartedParallel.pdf), [doMC](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doMC/doMC.pdf) and [doMC-Vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doMC/vignettes/gettingstartedMC.pdf) I've found so far cover only how to use parallel-computation in combination with `foreach`. Is there a way to speed up "sequential"-code as well?

Imagine it like splitting one file into multiple files and executing each file with a different instance of `R`. E.g.

```
## <run on core1>
data1 <- getData1()
dataResult1 <- doComplexAlgorithm1(data1)
## </run on core1>

## <run on core2>
data2 <- getData2()
dataResult2 <- doComplexAlgorithm2(data2)
## </run on core2>

## <run on core3>
data3 <- getData3()
dataResult3 <- doComplexAntotherAlgorithm3(data3)
## </run on core3>

## <run on core4>
data4 <- getData4()
dataResult4 <- doComplexNotSoComplexAlgorithm4(data4)
## </run on core4>
```

Thanks in advance!

(R `v.3.2.1`, RStudio `v.0.99.451`)

Answer (score 2):

In the base (single-process) scenario, you'd use `mapply`, passing it a list of your functions:

```
mapply(function(getData, doAlg) {
    dat <- getData()
    doAlg(dat)
},
getData=list(getData1, getData2, getData3, getData4),
doAlg=list(algorithm1, algorithm2, algorithm3, algorithm4))
```

In the parallel processing case, you can use `clusterMap`:

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster()
clusterMap(cl, function(getData, doAlg) {
    dat <- getData()
    doAlg(dat)
},
getData=list(getData1, getData2, getData3, getData4),
doAlg=list(algorithm1, algorithm2, algorithm3, algorithm4))
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to do what I try to do with images.
I've got some images and some computation on them, which by itself takes quite long. The way I do is have a list of files, and:

```
foreach (i =1:length(fileList)) %dopar% { 
    - load data
    - do something
    - write result to disk
}
```

It's just as you say, each set of data (file), is processed on its own core provided your system has enough memory to hold it all at once.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The problem is, that the operations done in the different sections differ greatly. It is a mixture of a sql-command and a few data preparation processes. I enhanced my question to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

So you don't need any memory sharing or communication among each job, or they are independent jobs.

The foreach or lapply paradigm are more designed for splitting a loop or vector process. For totally individual jobs, you need to wrap another layer to make it into a loop.

Wrap each section into a function, put all functions into a list, then call each function in loop.

```
fun_list <- list(
  fun_1 <- function() {
    data1 <- getData1()
    doComplexAlgorithm1(data1)
},
    fun_2 <- function() {
    data2 <- getData1()
    doComplexAlgorithm2(data2)
},
...
)
```